# Spring webflux proxy upload file to s3 efficient?

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-webflux

i want to upload file to AWS s3 using Mono spring webflux, but i can not calculate file size without allocate file to memory that is not efficient. Anyone help me ?

Comment: did you consider multipart upload?

Comment: yes, i use filepart, but content-length header is all size of body not only file size